# Setting backgroundColor of custom UIButton class has no effect?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard, uibackgroundcolor

I have a UIButton subclass I've created called `TimerButton` which has two methods to set the color of it:

```
class TimerButton: UIButton {

    func setRunning() {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }

    func setStopped() {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemMint
    }
}
```

My TimerButton is also representing in a StoryBoard, where I've set the color to `systemMint` and added the custom class to the button presented:

[image]
[image]

In my `ViewController` I have the button linked as an `IBAction`, and an `IBObject` called `button`. I call the methods `self.button.setRunning()` and `self.button.setStopped()` in the `IBAction` that is linked to it in the storyboard based on when its running.

However the color never changes from the `systemMint` that was set in the Storyboard

How do I get the appropriate color to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `Filled` button style, so you need to use the button configuration to change the color:

```
class TimerButton: UIButton {
    func setRunning() {
        self.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .systemYellow
    }
    func setStopped() {
        self.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .systemMint
    }
}
```